# Check for ModelState errors in posted FormCollection on different Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I have a WebPage Controller that handles all my public side of things on the website.

I have an Enquiry table to insert details of information typed in a contact form.

On the contact page it posts to the WebPage Controller with the contact form information.

How do I check that the form collection validates against the expected Enquiry table?  My model has DataAnnotations if that helps.

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I realised I can do a TryUpdateModel but to put the information into my object but how do I passback the validation information eg/they didn't type in their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that even though I do a TryUpdateModel on a different model it would get returned in the modelstate so I used a prefix and so validationsummary would pick it up

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out how Nerd Dinner does it?  They extend the model with a validate method which checks values and build a validation errors collection that can then be passed back to the view to render.

It's quite a neat solution.

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870313/nerd-dinner-validation-rules-question)

[And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489188/server-side-validation-how-to-pass-errors-to-view-in-mvc)

[And this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net-mvc+server+validation)

Comment: Problem is I dont want to manually check every field and then add to modelstate.  After I do TryUpdateModel is there not something I can do which checks the DataAnnotations requirements and then it determines that ColumnA is missing then I can add to ModelState